# What is this jQuery statement doing?

Tags: jquery, coldfusion-8

```
function setReplicate()  
{
    $('.replicate').live("click",function(){  
    var nm=$(this).attr('name');  
    var cntr=$(this).attr('cntr');  
    var vpmo=$(this).attr('vpmo');  
    var vl=$(this).parent().prev().find("select").val();  
    $('[name="'+nm+'"][vpmo="'+ vpmo + '"]').each(function() {  
    if ($(this).attr("cntr") >= cntr)   
    $(this).parent().prev().find("select").val(vl);  
    });  
    });  
}
```

There is a project number with systems assigned to the project.  Each system has details about it and are outputted by looping over tables.  Within the table is a select list - some will have values prepopulated but others will not.  Within the  is the select list and an icon with a jQuery selector tied to it so that when the icon is clicked, the value in the select list is applied to the other systems wihtin the project.  This function works perfectly as long as the values in the select list does not have a value prepopulated (read from the database during page load - noajax or other manipulations are occurring).  No errors are generated and if I put in alerts, I get the values I expect until the

```
if ($(this).attr("cntr") >= cntr)  
    $(this).parent().prev().find("select").val(vl);  
  });
```

so I suspect the issue is within here.

The following code is generated for a coldfusion custom tag and this is what FF sees when I view generated source code:

```
<select name="resource" id="resource_12345_200002" class="resource_12345" selection="">
<option>Donald Duck</option
<option>Mickey Mouse</option>
...
<option>Goofy</option>  
</selected>

<select name="resource" id="resource_12345_200003" class="resource_12345" selection="Donald Duck">  
<option select="selected">Donald Duck</option>  
<option>Mickey Mouse</option>  
...  
<option>Goofy</option>  
</select>
```

The value, 'Donald Duck' should be able to be applied to the remaining select items from this point in the list and below (thus the reason for the cntr >= cntr values.

I've got someone in the office going to look this over with me in the morning so don't spend too much time looking at this.  I just was hoping to get a head start.

TIA

Comment: >= will work with numbers. Comparing text strings will result in nothing useful for you. What are you really trying to compare between the strings? Also I don't see any html attribute named cntr so that will be returning null.

Comment: I don't see a `cntr` or `vpmo` attribute in your markup, so it would help us help you if you provided that markup as well. @Thomas, if `cntr` is compared to a number string of the same length it'll work... e.g `if ('1' < '5') { alert('true'); } // alerts true`, but  `if ('11' < '2') { alert('true'); } // alerts true` will also alert true.

Comment: @thomas-brashington @fudgey cntr is abbreviation for counter and the numbers would be the same length.  An example of a number is 100005.  VPMO is just a text string variable.    `<input type=text name=vpmo id=vpmo>`

Comment: Turns out some of the vpmo numbers had a trailing space in it (the vpmo are being imported that way).  We applied a trim to the statements and now this is performing as expected.  Thanks for the review guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out some of the vpmo numbers had a trailing space in it (the vpmo are being imported that way). We applied a trim to the statements and now this is performing as expected. Thanks for the review guys.